# How to write an if(or switch) statement to check all the values of an array in one go in php

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to check ALL the values of an array in an if statement in one go in php?

E.g.
I have the array:

```
$testing = array(true, true, true);
```

I want to do something like

```
if($testing == (true, true, true)){
   //do something
}else if ($testing == (true, true, false)){
   //do something else
}
etc...
```

If it's not possible, does anyone have any ideas about how this can be done?
Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like "let's go back to the drawing board" type of problem you have there. What do you want to accomplish, assuming such thing would be possible?

Comment: calling all vars $testing is making your code imposable to understand, i could interpret it many ways

Comment: Downvotes without explaination are so... ***constructive***, yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare them like this:

```
$testing = Array(true, true, true);

if($testing == array(true, true, true)){
   //do something
}else if ($testing == array(true, true, false)){
   //do something else
}
```

You don't need to use the same variable `$testing` again. Just create a new array to compare it with.

Comment: It might be even with `[ ... ]` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

yes, **in_array()**  function check the string in the given array.

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
   echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
 echo "Got mac"; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
$a = array('a','b','d');
if ($a == array('a','b','c')) {
    // first

} elseif ($a == array('a','b','d')) {
    // second
}
```

Comment: I believe that's exactly what I said :)

Comment: Seems so, I typed a bit slower :)

Answer (score 0):

Try array_diff:

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you need a script like this:**

```
$testing = array(true, true, true);

foreach ($testing as $key = > $value)
{
   if ($value != TRUE)
      {
       die();
      }
   else
      {
       // do something
      }
}
```